# Double filter django

Tags: python, django

I started learning django and decided to create a clothing store. I would like to know how to make a filter to display products like men's - t-shirt || Female - T-shirt?
At the moment, I have learned to display only by category T-shirts, hoodies and so on. How to make double filtering so that there is sorting by female and male?

views.py

```
class StuffCategory(ListView):
    model = Stuff
    template_name = 'shop/shop.html'
    context_object_name = 'stuffs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Stuff.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'], draft=False)

class StuffView(ListView):
    model = Stuff
    template_name = 'shop/shop.html'
    context_object_name = 'stuffs'
    paginate_by = 3
```

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('category', kwargs={'category_slug': self.slug})



class Gender(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Гендер'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Гендеры'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('gender', kwargs={'gender_slug': self.slug})


class Stuff(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField()
    composition = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    instruction = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    manufacturer_country = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    gender = models.ForeignKey(Gender, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    size = models.ManyToManyField(Size)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='items/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    draft = models.BooleanField("Черновик", default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вещь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Вещи'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('stuff_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: You can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) or you can try [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass parameters in the url as you do with category_slug

```
class StuffCategory(ListView):
    # ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Stuff.objects.filter(draft=False)
        if self.kwargs.get('category_slug'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'])
        if self.kwargs.get('gender_slug'):
            queryset = queryset.filter(gender__slug=self.kwargs['gender_slug'])
        # ... and others if you want!
        return queryset
```

Comment: Thank you, It works! But now I don't know how to pass href in html file

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Q objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

> Keyword argument queries – in filter(), etc. – are “AND”ed together. If you need to execute more complex queries (for example, queries with OR statements), you can use Q objects.

```
from django.db.models import Q

Stuff.objects.filter(Q(gender__name__iexact='men') | Q(gender__name__iexact='female'))
```